# .toggle() not registering on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css, click

Attempting to toggle a div display on and off with a button click. Relevant code below.

HTML

```
<li>
    <a id="academic_link" href="#">
        <button id="academic_button">Academic</button>
    </a>
</li>

<div id="legend_content">
<div id="academic_content">
```

CSS

```
#legend_content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px 10px 25px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#academic_button {
    background-color: black; /* Test colors later -- Green - #4CAF50 */
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom: none;
    color: white;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 10px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 11.5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 78px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#academic_button").click(function() {
        $("legend_content").toggle();
    });
});
```

I feel like the click isn't even getting registered.

Comment: forgot a `#`.  Write like this:  `$("#legend_content").toggle();`

Comment: `$("legend_content").toggle();` should be `$("#legend_content").toggle();`

Comment: @Taplar , thnx. fixed it

Comment: This should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a # before legend_content as it is an id.

```
$("#legend_content").toggle();
```

Comment: a `.` is the selector for class, a `#` is the selector for id

Comment: Glanced over it too quickly.